# Get the file ID of a Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The basic case is 2 files:

1. Admin file. Library.
2. User file.

I use a library file as admin file, and store some settings on its sheet. In a User file, I have a code, that needs an access to Admin file.

The code in a library:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

won't work, it will return the User file when running from a library.

---

Is there a code to have an access to a library file (spreadsheet)?

[image]

I need this because do not want to hardcode the ID of a library, in order to make it work with different copies of a library file.

I think of a solution similar to Excel's:

```
Set book = ThisWorkbook
```

The code in Excel will always return file where the code is.

Comment: You want to retrieve file ID of a library from a project file installed the library. If my understanding is correct, do you know the file ID of project file that the library was installed? The file ID is used to retrieve the file ID of installed library. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike, I know the file ID and the project ID, but I need to get the file form a library code without the need to hardcode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample script? Recently, Google Apps Script API was added. By this, users can easily manage GAS project files. This sample script uses this API.

In order to use this sample script, please do the following flow.

### Installation

- Enable Google Apps Script API at API console.

  - If you have already opened the script editor, you can access there by [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/script.googleapis.com).
- Retrieve current scopes.

  - On script editor, File -> Project properties -> Scopes
  - Copy scopes.
- Add a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects` to the Manifests file (appsscript.json) of the script editor. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects.readonly` may be able to be also used in this situation.

  - On script editor, View -> Show manifest file
  - Add `"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "### other scopes ###"]` to appsscript.json, and save.

    - In this sample, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` is also required.
    - If your script needs other scopes, please add them here.
- Copy and paste this sample script, and run. And please authorize.

  - Please input Identifier for the library and fileId of project file that the library was installed.

### Sample script :

```
function fetch(id) {
  var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + id + "/content";
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  return JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText()).files;
}

function main() {
  var Identifier = "### Identifier ###"; // Identifier for the library.
  var fileId = "### fileId ###"; // fileId of project file that the library was installed.

  var files = fetch(fileId);
  var library = files.filter(function(e){return (e.type == "JSON" && e.name == "appsscript")})[0];
  var source = JSON.parse(library.source);
  var libraryId = source.dependencies.libraries.filter(function(e){return e.userSymbol == Identifier})[0].libraryId;
  var libraryCode = fetch(libraryId);
  Logger.log(libraryCode)
}
```

### Note :

- The flow of this sample script is as follows.

  1. Retrieve the library ID from fileId of project file that the library was installed.
  2. Retrieve the library code from the library ID.
- The result of `libraryCode` is json data. This data is raw data of project. You can retrieve the library code from it.

### References :

- [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/)
- [Manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

Unfortunately, in current stage, I think that it cannot achieve to retrieve Spreadsheet ID that the library was installed under the situation.

Comment: Thank you. It's very useful information. I'm sorry, I can't accept this answer because I'm looking for a more simple solution, without API usage.

Comment: I'm very interested in the code. I've tried the main function and got the error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "filter" of undefined`. Guess, I made smth wrong? My `files` object appears to be `undefined`...

Comment: Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Max-Makhrov/ea98312e602a20f86726e21fb595c80a) with my code.

Comment: @Max Makhrov I'm sorry for the inconvenience. About ``var Identifier = ""``, this is the identifier for using library. That might be the same to filename of the library. For example, when the library is installed as the identifier of ``Library``, users use the function of ``sample()`` in the library by ``Library.sample()``. At that time, please input ``var Identifier = "Library"``.

Comment: @Max Makhrov Even if you tried above modification, when it didn't work, can I ask you about the error? In my sample script, there are 2 filter. Which is it? And at that time, can I ask you about the values of files or source.dependencies.libraries? By those, the reason of the error may be able to found.

Comment: @Max Makhrov Can I confirm about what you want to do? You want to retrieve file ID and whole code of library without using some APIs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you again for your time. 1. I had a wrong `Identifier`, it's correct now, thank you. 2. in my code `var files = fetch(fileId);` gives `undefined`, so it may be the case with `fileId` of with fetching. 3. I've edited the Q, I'm sorry if I confused you about my goal, I need a spreadsheet  ID, where the library is stored. Gues, it's impossible =(.

Comment: @Max Makhrov I could understand that you need Spreadsheet ID which installed the library. Yes. I think that this is very difficult question. So can I ask you about 4 questions? 1. You have already known the file ID of the library? 2. You have already known the filename of the library? 3. The filename of library is only one in Google Drive? 4. The filename of Spreadsheet that you want to know is only one in Google Drive? If I have 4 YESs, I thought that I might be able to find the workaround, I would like to challenge it.

Comment: thank you. I wanted to share my project with a user without the need to interact the code. I had to save some settings, available to any user file. And then I faced with google quotas and had to store all settings in a spreadsheet, and read it with `getValues()`. If you think, it's impossible, please mention it in your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Max Makhrov I could understand the situation. Unfortunately, in current stage, I think that it cannot achieve to retrieve Spreadsheet ID that the library was installed under the situation. I'm sorry. But I could study from your question and discussions. If I found the workaround in the future, I will tell you. Thank you.